# okd gpg error: can't check signature no public key

Tags: openstack, okd

I'm deploying a okd cluster in openstack, and I'm having the following problem when installing the bootstrap/workers/cp machines:

[image]

I followed the steps of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d03xg2PKOPg) video, however, I configured the install-config.yaml with your the pull-secret `{"auths":{"fake":{"auth":"aWQ6cGFzcwo="}}}` instead, as documented in the OKD documentation and the ssh public key of the machine.

The commands in the boot menu for the installation are the following:

```
nameserver=10.0.27.10
coreos.inst.install_dev=/dev/vdb
coreos.inst.image_url=http://10.0.27.10:8080/okd4/fcos
coreos.inst.insecure=yes 
coreos.inst.ignition_url=http://10.0.27.10:8080/okd4/master.ign
```

Comment: What version of OKD are you using?

Comment: @larsks 4.7.0-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I updated the fcos and fcos.sig to the [lastest](https://builds.coreos.fedoraproject.org/prod/streams/stable/builds/37.20221106.3.0/x86_64/fedora-coreos-37.20221106.3.0-metal.x86_64.raw.xz) version and now it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Search administrator accounts...

[ OK ]

Checking UIDs....

[ OK ]

Checking chkarp tool...

[FOUND]

Consistency check /etc/group file....

[ OK ]

Test group files (grpck)....

[OK]

Checking login shells...

[ WARNING ]

Checking non unique group ID's....

[ OK ]

Checking non unique group names...

[OK]

Checking LDAP authentication support

[NOT ENABLED ]

Check /etc/sudoers file

[ NOT FOUND ]

[Press [ENTER] to continue, or [CTRL]+C to stop ]

[+] Shells

Checking console TTYs...

[ WARNING 1

Checking shells from /etc/shells...

Result: found 6 shells (valid shells: 6)

[Press [ENTER] to continue, or [CTRL]+C to stop ]

[+] File systems

[FreeBSD] Querying UFS mount points (fstab)....

[ OK ]

Query swap partitions (fatab)...

[ OK ]

Testing swap partitions...

[OK]

Checking for old files in /tmp...

[ WARNING 1

Checking /tmp sticky bit...

[ OK ]